# Invalid syntax occurring in my python code

Tags: python

So, I've been working on a code, but I ran into a problem. I would get an invalid syntax. How can I fix this?

```
print ("Ok, type away")
    number1 = input("Input the first number \n")
    symbol = input("Input your desired operation (+,-,*,/) \n")
    number2 = input("Input the second number \n")
    if symbol == "+":
        output = (int(number1) + int(number2))
    elif symbol == "-":
        output = (int(number1) - int(number2))
    elif symbol == "*":
        output = (int(number1) * int(number2))
    elif symbol == "/":
        output = (int(number1) / int(number2))

    else:
        print ("Something went wrong, ty again")
        number1 = input("Input the first number \n")
        symbol = input("Input your desired operation (+,-,*,/) \n")
        number2 = input("Input the second number \n")
        if symbol == "+":
            output = (int(number1) + int(number2))
        elif symbol == "-":
            output = (int(number1) - int(number2))
        elif symbol == "*":
            output = (int(number1) * int(number2))
        elif symbol == "/":
            output = (int(number1) / int(number2))
    print ("I'm thinking, Please be Patient")
    time.sleep ((random.randint(2,9))

    print ((output))
```

Note: it's the last print.

Answer (score 1):

The line before the last `print` has unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: Balance the parentheses.

Comment: What do you mean? (sry, I'm noob)

Comment: There are 3 `(` but only 2 `)`.

Comment: wait.... I'm thinking, Please be Patient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vlad\Desktop\AI.py", line 43, in <module>
    time.sleep (random.randint(2,9))
NameError: name 'random' is not defined

Comment: How can I fix this?